# How to set serviceUnavailableAlertEnabled in RestKit v0.20.0

Tags: ios6, restkit, afnetworking

In Restkit versions before v0.20.0 it used to be a simple enough to check for service unavailability and show appropriate responses.

```
objectManager.client.serviceUnavailableAlertEnabled = YES;
```

How can we achieve the same in latest RestKit?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Figured it out myself.

Since RKClient is no more in the latest RestKit it has been replaced by the AFHTTPClient from AFNetworking. The wrapper for reachability in AFNetworking is simple enough to use.

- Firstly add the SystemConfiguration.framework to your project.
- Then add `#import <SystemConfiguration/SystemConfiguration.h>` to your `.pch` file.

Finally register a callback block whenever the network reachability changes.

```
[objectManager.HTTPClient setReachabilityStatusChangeBlock:^(AFNetworkReachabilityStatus status) {
    if (status == AFNetworkReachabilityStatusNotReachable) {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"No network connection"
                                                        message:@"You must be connected to the internet to use this app."
                                                       delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }
}];
```

This also works when the app is started when no internet connection is present.

Comment: Just in case someone stumbles upon an error like `"No visible @interface for HTTPCLIENT declares the selector setReachabilityStatusChangeBlock"` while implementing this answer using RestKit (which inlcudes AFNetworking): Also make sure you put `#import <SystemConfiguration/SystemConfiguration.h>` before `#import <RestKit/RestKit.h>` like stated in this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17456070/332248).