# HttpClient setReachabilityStatusChangedBlock declares no interface

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking

Trying to use AFNetworkings ReachabilityStatusChanged but getting

"No visible @interface for HTTPCLIENT declares the selector setReachabilityStatusChangeBlock"

But HttpClient has that function. Anyone know why this is happening?

```
AFHTTPClient *client = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://stat-api.herokuapp.com/"]];
[client setReachabilityStatusChangeBlock:^(AFNetworkReachabilityStatus status){

    NSLog(@"%d", status);

}];
```

/// UPDATE ///////////

Here is my .pch file

```
#ifdef __OBJC__
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>
#import "NSDate+Helper.h"
#import "NSEntityDescription+RKAdditions.h"
#import "UIAlertView+MKBlockAdditions.h"
#import "UIActionSheet+MKBlockAdditions.h"
#import "MKBlockAdditions.h"
#import "NSObject+MKBlockAdditions.h"
#import "NSString+Extra.h"
#import "UIView+Additions.h"
#import "ObjectiveSugar.h"
#import "NSNotificationCenter+UniqueNotif.h"
#import "STUIColor+Custom.h"
#import "NSObject+STNSObjectAdditions.h"
#import "UIView+Gradientcy.h"
#import "NSString+USStateMap.h"
#import "STUITextField.h"
#import "UIImage+UIImageCrop.h"
#import "UIBorderLabel.h"
#import <SystemConfiguration/SystemConfiguration.h>



#endif
```

Comment: Clean your project and delete Xcode derived data as necessary. If you have SystemConfiguration correctly linked and imported, everything should work fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Move

```
#import <SystemConfiguration/SystemConfiguration.h>
```

right after this line:

```
#ifdef __OBJC__
```

Comment: This is my problem. I guess compile order matters in my .pch file because having it be the 10th one imported instead of the 1st one imported caused this bug. Making it first fixed it. To test, I made it the 10th import again and the bug came back.

Comment: +1 I'm using AFNetworking with RestKit and now that I came across this I guess it makes sense to put this before the `#import <RestKit/RestKit.h>`.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're using a version of AFNetworking that have this method?

Also, check this warning from [the docs](http://afnetworking.github.io/AFNetworking/Classes/AFHTTPClient.html#//api/name/setReachabilityStatusChangeBlock%3a):

> **Warning**: This method requires the `SystemConfiguration` framework.
>
> Add it in the active target’s “Link Binary With Library” build phase, and add `#import <SystemConfiguration/SystemConfiguration.h>` to the header prefix of the project (`Prefix.pch`).

Comment: When I command click the setReachabilityStatusChangeBlock it takes me to that block of code.

Comment: Are you sure you added `SystemConfiguration` correctly? Because this method is inside a `#ifdef _SYSTEMCONFIGURATION_H`, so if it's not imported the method won't be compiled.